# Icingaweb2 on a Server doesn't start

Tags: icinga

So, I installed Icingaweb2 on a Ubuntu 16.04 server, but when I type in the `IP/icingaweb2` I only get the message

```
<?php
/*! Icinga Web 2 | (c) 2014 Icinga Development Team | GPLv2+ */

require_once '/usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/webrouter.php';
```

and not the Icingaweb2 Interface.

Did I forget to configurate something? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a PHP issue, need to upgrade to 7.0.

Run this:

```
apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Comment: This answer is on the low quality post list. If the code you provide, please provide some additional text explaining why it works. This way, you may get some upvotes and gain some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem here is that Ubuntu 16.04 behaves differently when it comes to loading the PHP module. As such the packages require a specific fix only applied for 16.04

There was a discussion in German over [here](https://monitoring-portal.org/index.php?thread/36593-leere-seite-nach-installation/) which turned into a research what changed with the latest Ubuntu release. One thing is - they prefer mpm_event over mpm_prefork as a module. The problem is - the PHP apache module is only compiled for mpm_prefork support but fails heavily when used with mpm_event (see this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser/767699#767699) as well).

While the Ubuntu package may satisfy the dependency issues, it cannot forcefully change the mpm* modules. So now we have an open issue for Icinga Web 2 in order to update the documentation for making it work on Ubuntu 16.04. Until this is done please kindly check [this solution](https://dev.icinga.org/issues/12285).

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-dom php7.0-gd

vim /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
<set timezone>

#set the correct worker
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod mpm_prefork
systemctl restart apache2
```

The PHP module is not compiled for supporting the mpm_event module at this time. PHP 7.0 itself may be thread-safe but not anything else running in that context of the apache webserver then. Not sure why Ubuntu chooses to not set mpm_prefork by default - upgrades pretty much hurt and I couldn't find any good changelog for that.